# Is there a list of the approximate dates when the various versions of achemso were released?

Tags: achemso

## Question

I am using the [`achemso` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso) to typeset a manuscript in the American Chemical Society format.  Near the end of the [package documentation for the `achemso` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/achemso/achemso.pdf), there is a section, **Change History** (section 8), that lists the versions of `achemso` and what was modified in each version.  However, that listing only includes the version numbers, not the (approximate) dates, or even just the years, when each version was released.

Is there a listing somewhere of the (approximate) dates that each version of `achemso` was released?

## Reason for asking question

The reason that I have asked the above question is that I am using MiKTeX on Windows, but my boss uses TeXShop on Mac.  In MiKTeX, packages are automatically downloaded if needed.  Thus, the first time I compiled a file with `\usepackage{achemso}`, MiKTeX automatically downloaded and installed the `achemso` package.

I am not familiar with TeXShop or Mac, but it seems that in TeXShop packages are *not* installed automatically.  It seems that in that system, one needs to periodically "update" TeXShop to obtain the latest ctan packages such as `achemso`.  My boss knows the *date* of release of the TeXShop version that he has on his computer, but he doesn't know the version of `achemso` that he has in his current TeXShop.  So I am trying to "work backwards" and try to determine the *approximate* version of `achemso` that he has in his current TeXShop.  For example, if his TeXShop is dated May 2012, then *perhaps* it is reasonable to guess that at least the 2011 version of `achemso` is included.  With this guess of 2011, I would like to find out from the **Change History** what features he probably has in his distribution of `achemso`.

Comment: You should ask @JosephWright, [the developer of `achemso`](https://github.com/josephwright/achemso)

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks for the suggestion!  Is there a way that I can directly ask a user such as JosephWright a question, short of sending him an e-mail?

Comment: You can try [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Joseph's a regular visitor :)

Comment: also take a look at the mercurial repo history: http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/hg/achemso/

Comment: Could you be more specific as to your requirements? There are a lot of versions, and while I can list all of them from the development system, this looks like a lot of work. I assume there is something else you are really after.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you!  Yes, you are right, there is something else I am really after.  I have edited my question above to describe what I am looking for.

Comment: Besides the fact that TeXshop only is an editor and no TeX distribution: your boss could add `\listfiles` to his preamble, compile, and then look in the log file if he wants to find out the version of `achemso` he uses...

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks.  Can he also use `\listfiles` to determine which TeX distribution he has?  Do you have any guesses as to what the name of the TeX distribution might be?

Comment: If he's on OSX the distribution is probably MacTeX.

Comment: @Andrew the first line in the log file may tell it (with or without `\listfiles`)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are: https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/achemso.
It's not listing the version numbers beside the dates, but you can can count back from the last.